# I want to code fibonacci series program in C but I am getting the last element as negative

Tags: c, fibonacci

I don't know why am I getting the last number as negative.

I want to get the output as 0 1 1 ...  'n' numbers  (fibonacci series)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a=-1,b=1,c=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        c=a+b;
        printf("%d",c);
        a=b;
        b=c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What `n` do you input , maybe the result already out of bound

Comment: my n value is 48, i am not getting any error message. But my output last element alone is negative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely out of int range

```
1836311903 //before last
-1323752223 //last
```

the max int is 2,147,483,647

If you want more than n=48, you must declare a,b,c as long type

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    long a=-1,b=1,c=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      c=a+b;
      printf("%ld\n",c);
      a=b;
      b=c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```